# Сортировка файла с помощью Python

Tags: python, файлы

Имеется txt файл с содержанием:

```
    "STEAM_0:0:82310879"    
    {
        "name"  "123"
        "deny"  
        {
        }
        "allow" 
        {
        }
        "group" "operator"
    }

    "STEAM_0:0:11310879"    
    {
        "name"  "321"
        "deny"  
        {
        }
        "allow" 
        {
        }
        "group" "operator"
    }
```

Требуется привести его к виду по типу:

```
    id = "STEAM_0:0:00000000" name = "123" group = "123"
```

Код, который хотел использовать, но выдает он None:

```
    def find_steamid (sid):
        fcopy = open('users_copy.html')
        word = str(sid)
        soup = BeautifulSoup (fcopy, 'lxml')
        f = soup.find('h1').find(text = str(word))
        print(f)
        return 
    find_steamid('STEAM_0:0:88310879')
```

Код номер два, без html:

```
f = open("users_copy.txt", 'r')
f.readline()
    new = []
    for lines in f:
        if lines == '   "allow"':
            print('1')
        if lines == '   "deny"':
            print('1')
        if lines == '{':
            print('1')
        if lines == '}':
            print('1')
        if lines == '   {':
            print('1')
        if lines == '   }':
            print('1')
        else:
            new.append(lines)
    print(str(new))
```

Comment: Попробуй сам чего то написать. Хотя бы код для открытия и записи. И какую то логику, если не получается у самого сделать работоспособную все равно пиши. Здесь не freelance, здесь сидят программисты и *помогают* друг другу если что то не получается, а не делают работу друг за друга.

Comment: Перефразируя вышесказанное. Здесь ты делаешь себе код сам. Но если чего то не получается, можно зайти и спросить *конкретно* что именно не получается и как это сделать. А за полным выполнением задачи загугли freelance и походи по сайтам из выдачи.

Comment: Да, чего-то я совсем попутал. В общем. У меня появилась такая идея: сделать копию этого файла в расширении html (потом выяснилось, что все сразу переводится в одну строку, что очень удобно), след. шагом было импортировать bs4 для чтения и парсинга инфо с файла. Получилось вот это нечто:

Comment: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def create_copy ():
 folder = 'D:/SteamCMD/steamapps/common/EqRp/garrysmod/data/ulib/'
 forg = open(str(folder)+"users.txt",'r')
 forg_read = forg.read()
 fcopy = open("users_copy.html", 'w')
 fcopy_write = fcopy.write('<h1>'+str(forg_read)+'<h1>')
 forg.close()
 fcopy.close()
create_copy()

#def find_steamid (sid):
# fcopy = open('users_copy.html')
# word = str(sid)
# soup = BeautifulSoup (fcopy, 'lxml')
# f = soup.find('h1').find(text = str(word))
# print(f)
# return`

Comment: Свой код добавляешь так: делаешь редактирование твоего вопроса, внизу пишешь update1: и дальше с новой строки вставляешь полноценный код.

Comment: Отредактировал, уж извините меня, немного не подумал...

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно тебя понял то вот так

```
stream_list = []
str_list = []
with open("1.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
     for line in file.readlines():
        if "STEAM" in line:
             stream_list.append(line.strip())
        else:
            line = line.replace('}', '').replace('{', '').strip()
            str_list.append(line)
res = []
new_list = ''.join(str_list).replace('"', ' ').split(' ')
int_list = []
for i in new_list:
    if i.isdigit() is True:
        int_list.append(i)

for i in range(len(stream_list)):
    res.append({'id': stream_list[i], "name": int_list[i], "group": int_list[i]})

print(res)
```